# How to configure the bridge connection in linux

Tags: networking

Can someone help me how to configure bridge connection in linux and what are the command that being use.

I do really appreciate your help!

Comment: what bridge? [This one](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bridge)?

Answer (score 0):

I am new Debian Linux user. I want to setup Bridge for virtualised environments (KVM) running on Debian Linux.

By default, a private network bridge created when using Kernel-based Virtual Machine(KVM). You need to set up interfaces manually, avoiding conflicts with, network manager.If you want to assign IP addresses to your virtual machines and make them accessible from your LAN you need to setup network bridge.

The procedure to configure network bridge on Debian Linux is as follows:

Just use the ip command:

```
$ ip -f inet a s
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
$ sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces.d/br0
$ sudo systemctl restart network-manager
$ ip a s
$ ip r
$ ping -c 2 cyberciti.biz
$ brctl show
$ bridge link
```

Comment: googluck to your